# Como usar o Web api para controllers e MVC para view(Front-end)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, controller

olá, meu problema é o seguinte, estou fazendo um teste para estagio e o cara pediu pra fazer um projeto asp.net com mvc só para views, e web api só para controllers e uma outra camada para o banco só que eu não consegui fazer o mvc reconhecer os controllers no web api, são projetos distintos, são 3 projetos na mesma solution, alguém poderia me ajudar? obrigado

Comment: Poste o código/imagens do projeto para que alguém possa ajudá-lo mais facilmente.

Comment: O Controller está em outra solution? basta registrar no global.asax passando o nome da .dll

Comment: Cara, eu nao manjo muito asp, eu sei refenciar os projeto, mas como eu saberia o nome desta dll?

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte checklist:

- Se você está testando no browser, verificar se o [HttpGet] está no metodo da controller que você está tentando chamar.
- Verifique se na classe WebApiConfig está registrado ao menos a rota Default
- Verifique se as referências do projeto estão certas.
- Nesse caso como vc está testando o web.api você tem que defini-lo como Startup Project para rodar o projeto.